# bind multiple values using ng-bind

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-bind

Can I bind multiple values using ng-bind like so :

```
<p ng-bind="instructor.first_name instructor.last_name"></p>
```

Whenever I try this I get the following error:

Error: $parse:syntax Syntax Error

I know I can do the same using the curly braces

```
<p>{{instructor.first_name}}{{instructor.last_name}}</p>
```

but I would like to avoid this if I can since the rest of the code base uses ng-bind and I would to stay consistent. Thanks.

Comment: [Docs say no](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind)

Comment: Haven't tried this, but I think you have to treat `ng-bind` values as expressions; so try `instructor.first_name + " " + instructor.last_name`

Comment: No it doesn't but I am just going to reformat the html a bit more with `span` tags inside the `p` tag and use ng-bind on each of those. Thanks

Comment: @ChadWatkins Here's an example of it working: http://plnkr.co/edit/ls0AkKUpY7z0xNeY0xB3?p=preview

Comment: @AndrewBurgess Awesome, thank you. I had double quotes on the outside and I think that stopped it from working.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use "+" for concatenation of the expressions. The following should work for you: `<p ng-bind="(instructor.first_name) + (instructor.last_name)"></p>`.
You can even add filters there `<p ng-bind="(instructor.first_name | filterName) + (instructor.last_name)"></p>`.

Answer (score 7):

You can always use ng-bind-template to bind and format multiple expressions.  This is somewhat of a combination of your ng-bind and curly braces, but I think it's what you are looking for.

Your example would be:

```
<p ng-bind-template="{{instructor.first_name}} {{instructor.last_name}}"></p>
```

And of course there is also a ng-bind-html if you are looking to bind an html string.

Answer (score 2):

Following the same idea of past answers you can also use `ng-bind-html` if you want to concat any other chars, that was my case:

```
  <td ng-bind-html="( com.ref.number | highlight: searchTerm) + '-' + (com.ref.order)">
  </td>
```